# Program Flow - Unable to figure out why an ElseIf argument is ignored/skipped

Tags: vba, excel

Brief background - The Function “CompareFI” below compares 3 numbers (TRAC, BVAL, BGN) and checks if one number corroborates another within a % range (AllowVar).  TRAC would be considered the top source in this hierarchy, then BVAL and finally BGN. TRAC, BVAL, BGN will either be 0 or a numerical value >0.  I used Abs()  to make the range +/- for comparison purposes.

Issues/Question – I always thought in If, Then, Else logic, …if the first statement was not true/not met,  the program would go to the second statement, then third, etc.

For this function, the first “If” statement works fine.  The first “ElseIf” statement works unless the 2 numbers are outside the AllowVar - returns a "#Value!" in Excel.  Function will never reach the second “ElseIf”.   The “Else” statement only works for the first “If”.  I can’t figure out why if the first “If” works and the “ElseIf” statements are similar, why won’t the “Elseifs” work like the first “If”.

Thanks,

Jon

```
Function CompareFI(TRAC As Single, BVAL As Single, BGN As Single, AllowVar As Single)

If (TRAC > 0 And BVAL > 0) And (Abs(BVAL / TRAC - 1) <= AllowVar) Then
    CompareFI = TRAC & " Case 1"

ElseIf (TRAC > 0 And BGN > 0) And (Abs(BGN / TRAC - 1) <= AllowVar) Then
    CompareFI = TRAC & " Case 2"

ElseIf (BVAL > 0 And BGN > 0) And (Abs(BGN / BVAL - 1) <= AllowVar) Then
    CompareFI = BVAL & " Case 3"

Else
    CompareFI = "Check this security"

End If


End Function
```

Comment: It's much easier to debug a UDF if you call it from a VBA Sub instead of from the worksheet.  If there's an error you will see it: called from a sheet you just get `#Value!` which doesn't tell you much.

Comment: What values do you have that you felt should be going to the second ElseIf, but didn't? Give the TRAC, BVAL, BGN and AllowVar.

Comment: @TimWilliams - That is a really good idea, I appreciate the advice.  Thank you.

Comment: @PKatona - Another post pointed me in the right direction, thank you for taking the time to review.

Answer (score 2):

`If` statements do not short circuit in VBA, so you can't use them to guard against division by zero like this:

> ```
> If (TRAC > 0 And BVAL > 0) And (Abs(BVAL / TRAC - 1) <= AllowVar) Then
>     CompareFI = TRAC & " Case 1"
> ```

That code will check ***both*** `TRAC > 0 And BVAL > 0` and `Abs(BVAL / TRAC - 1) <= AllowVar` regardless of the result of the first parenthesized expression.  If you need to guard the second condition you either need to nest the `If` statement or use some other flow control or guard clause to make sure you don't divide by zero:

```
If (TRAC > 0 And BVAL > 0) Then
    If (Abs(BVAL / TRAC - 1) <= AllowVar) Then
        CompareFI = TRAC & " Case 1"
        Exit Function
    End If
End If
If (TRAC > 0 And BGN > 0) Then
    If (Abs(BGN / TRAC - 1) <= AllowVar) Then
        CompareFI = TRAC & " Case 2"
        Exit Function
    End If
End If
If (BVAL > 0 And BGN > 0) Then
    If (Abs(BGN / BVAL - 1) <= AllowVar) Then
        CompareFI = BVAL & " Case 3"
        Exit Function
    End If
End If
CompareFI = "Check this security"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your post and the exit function in your code really makes sense.  This was my first function, was hoping to do on my own but this is a lot tougher than I thought.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

FYI...

The nested elseif statements do work. The following test gave a positive result

```
Sub Test()
    Dim TRAC As Single, BVAL As Single, BGN As Single, AllowVar As Single
    TRAC = 3: BVAL = 2: BGN = 1: AllowVar = 1
    Debug.Print CompareFI(TRAC, BVAL, BGN, AllowVar)
    TRAC = 3: BVAL = 12: BGN = 1: AllowVar = 1
    Debug.Print CompareFI(TRAC, BVAL, BGN, AllowVar)
    TRAC = 3: BVAL = 12: BGN = 15: AllowVar = 1
    Debug.Print CompareFI(TRAC, BVAL, BGN, AllowVar)
    TRAC = 3: BVAL = 12: BGN = 150: AllowVar = 1
    Debug.Print CompareFI(TRAC, BVAL, BGN, AllowVar)
End Sub

Function CompareFI(TRAC As Single, BVAL As Single, BGN As Single, AllowVar As Single)

    If TRAC > 0 And BVAL > 0 And Abs(BVAL / TRAC - 1) <= AllowVar Then
        CompareFI = TRAC & " Case 1"
    ElseIf TRAC > 0 And BGN > 0 And Abs(BGN / TRAC - 1) <= AllowVar Then
        CompareFI = TRAC & " Case 2"
    ElseIf BVAL > 0 And BGN > 0 And Abs(BGN / BVAL - 1) <= AllowVar Then
        CompareFI = BVAL & " Case 3"
    Else
        CompareFI = "Check this security"
    End If

End Function
```

> Output

```
3 Case 1
3 Case 2
12 Case 3
Check this security
```

Comment: I need to learn to write functions as subs, will probably make my life easier.  Thanks for the post